# AlarmManager updating every time

Tags: java, android, widget, alarmmanager

I have next code for Widget.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {

public String FORCE_APDATA="com.example.widjet.FORCE_UDATA_SUKA";

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidget){

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget);
    AppWidgetManager appManager=AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.textView1, View.GONE);
    remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.PB1, View.VISIBLE);
    appManager.updateAppWidget(appWidget, remoteViews);
    Citata c=new Citata();
    String citats="";

        try {
            citats = String.valueOf(c.getCitata());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, citats);            

    Intent intent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(FORCE_APDATA);

    PendingIntent pIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.textView1, pIntent);


    AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                    60*60*1000,
                                    (60*60*1000)/2,                                     
                                    pIntent); 
    remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.textView1, View.VISIBLE);
    remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.PB1, View.GONE);
    appManager.updateAppWidget(appWidget, remoteViews);
}

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if(FORCE_APDATA.equals(intent.getAction())){

        AppWidgetManager appManager=AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        ComponentName thisWidget=new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        int[] appWidgetIds=appManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
        onUpdate(context,appManager,appWidgetIds);

    }
} 
}
```

Function `c.getCitata()` sleep 2 seconds and return date.
but, when I start this widget, i see only ProgressBar.If remove AlarmManager, all work and update when to touch widget. What I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to be clear, you have an OnClick pending intent that will exceute class MainActivity.class. You also have an AlarmManager that also sends the PendingIntent to open MainActivity.class an hour after the widget is first clicked, the 30mins after that. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want, if I click on widget he start update, and widget update every 30 minutes, but now (in this code) widget update every seconds. Where i made mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to check this as I'm away from a pc, but you need to increment the second argument by System.currentTimeInMillis(). What i think is happening is the alarm is detecting the time to trigger as being in the past, so it fires immediately. You need to change:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 60*60*1000, (60*60*1000)/2, pIntent);
```

To:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeInMillis() + 60*60*1000, (30*60*1000), pIntent);
```

However, since you are going to set the alarm everytime the widget is updated, can I recommend you change this from setRepeating to set. Otherwise, what will currently happen is your widget will update every hour only. Use Alarm Manager.set instead.

Edit: After reading your comment, please try this for AlarmManager.set, which is similar to what you were using before.

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+30*60*1000, pIntent);
```

or if you wish to use your the different mode as per your comment, do:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealTime()+30*60*1000, pIntent);
```

This will send the PendingIntent every 30 minutes, which will call onUpdate() in your widget, which will send the PendingIntent, etc.

In using AlarmManager, you have to realise the different modes you can use, as each require a different definition of time to supply. AlarmManager.RTC & AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP require the starting time period to be defined using System time since start of Epoch. AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME & AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP require your start time to be defined using time since boot (SystemClock.elapsedRealTime()). So in both instances, you are defining the start time in GLOBAL time ie the internal clock is at time A, you want the alarm to refresh the widget in 30 mins, so you have to tell the AlarmManager to send the PendingIntent in A+30mins. AlarmManager.setRepeating also takes a 3rd parameter, which is the subsequent delta in time to continue sending the PendingIntent. This can just be defined in LOCAL time ie just 30mins without the GLOBAL time increment.

I hope that is clear enough.

EDIT: A recommendation I'd make here though, is to define your time increment as a STATIC FINAL variable in a Utils class e.g.

```
public class Utils {
    public static final int WIDGET_UPDATE_INTERVAL   = 30*60*1000;
}
```

This gives you a simple way of adjusting the interval in a single place without having to modify the code in the method each time. Your alarm line then becomes:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+Utils.WIDGET_UPDATE_INTERVAL, pIntent);
```

Trust me, doing this can make life a lot easier further down the line.

Comment: I change my code on `alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,          
          AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,
          pIntent);`, and now application wait 30 minut and start update every second.

Comment: So still not what you want?

Comment: I've updated the answer and added more clarification (hopefully)!

Comment: thank you very match, your comment really helped me. now I testing different variant. if i will get successful result, i'll write).

Comment: I made like this `alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
          SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+((30*60*1000)/2),
          (60*60*1000)/2,
          pIntent); `
and my widget started updat every 30 minutes, but late he destroying. now i try catching this problem. thank you very match

Answer (score 0):

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast
```

should be used with a broadcast intent. For Activies, use `PendingIntent.getActivity`.

Comment: Updating is stopped,but `remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.textView1, pIntent);` don't worked

Comment: No, I use broadcast. if use `PendingIntent.getActivity` widget don't worked.